# Where can I find documentation for Hibernate's legacy hbm.xml mapping files?

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm, hbmxml

I have joined a new team, and their project is using pretty much exclusively legacy-style Hibernate Mapping files (`*.hbm.xml`) for their Hibernate set-up. The current documentation pretty much seems to restrict itself to mention that Hibernate still supports hbm files and that they will take precedence over annotations.

Can someone please provide a link to documentation that mainly deals with Hibernate's legacy Mapping Files? (Even older versions of the doc only seem to mention them in passing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Hibernate you use?
I found documentation for XML mapping for version 3.3 under this link.

[Hibernate Mapping doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html)

Comment: Looks like the change (i.e. the introduction of annotations) happened between version [3.5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration) and [3.6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of the hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/

This appears to be the latest reference to the hbm.xml mapping:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html